# NGRX How to get previous states?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an Ngrx Store using entities. I need to get previous versions of the state to be able to undo.  I used the below code but it is not working when I change from one component to another because for this to work I need to subscribe in the top component which is not the best in my case.  is it a way to get versions of the state by defining a selector or other way?

```
// The number of state transitions is given by the user (subscriber)
export const selectLastStateTransitions = (count: number, selector: any) => {
  return pipe(
    // Thanks to `createSelector` the operator will have memoization "for free"
    select(selector),
    // Combines the last `count` state values in array
    scan((acc, curr) => {

      const x = [curr, ...acc].filter((val, index) => index < count); // && val !== undefined);
      return x;

    }, [])
    // Equivalent to what is emitted by the selector
  );
};
```

Best,
Hmendezm

Comment: You can store previous state into a variable of component

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that but I thought that there is a better way to do by using reducers, selectors. When you use the redux dev tools, you can see that they have versions in the tool. I thought that maybe ngrx keep this chain of changes somewhere else.